# Probability - median and mean

Tags: probability, statistics, median

I'm having a difficult time with this one. Would be happy for some help.

I'm kind of gets why its true but can't manage to prove it.

Let $X$ be a random variable with median $\Bbb MX$ such that positive constants $a, b$ exist so that for all $t > 0$,
$P(|X − \Bbb MX| > t) ≤ ae^{−t^2/b}$.

Show that
$|\Bbb MX−\Bbb EX|≤min(\sqrt{ab},a\sqrt{b\pi}/2)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

For one upper bound I don't think you have to use the fact that you are dealing with the median:

If you define $Y:=\vert X-\mathbb{M}(X)\vert$, then $\mathbb{E}[Y]\geq \vert \mathbb{E}[X]-\mathbb{M}(X)\vert$ by the triangle inequality for expectations.
Using the continuous tail-sum formula,

$$ \mathbb{E}[Y]=\int _0^\infty\mathbb{P}(Y>t)dt, $$

and the assumed inequality we get that $\mathbb{E}[Y]\leq \int_0^\infty ae^{-\frac{t^2}{b}}dt= \frac{a\sqrt{b\pi} }{\sqrt{2}}$.

I don't know how to obtain the other bound, but maybe this will help.

Comment: thank you! anyone knows to solve the other bound?

Comment: I prove that:    |MZ − EZ| ≤ sqrt(Var(Z)).  is that helpful?

Comment: @tomersher You can add it in an additional answer, so people might cooment if it is indeed helpful. There is an undecipherable block in your comment, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @tomersher You can also edit it into the body of your original psot.

Comment: I solved it:

just use the above with Y^2 instead of Y and the use the Jansen's inequality :)